# Rename files in multiple directories with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Lets say I have the following directory structure in Linux

```
dir1
........file1
dir2
........file2
dir3
.
.
.
dir x
...... file x
```

How can I rename all files file1-filex to the same name file?

Comment: Is it just the last one that has a space in the directory and filename?

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. Could you be a bit more specific what you want?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: It was clear enough for @funkyjelly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below would search for files in your current dir and all subdirs and will rename them. You'd just need to replace a_new_file_name with the new filename needed :

```
for file in $(find . -type f); do mv "$file" $(dirname "$file")/a_new_file_name; done
```